# Altium error: Un-connected Pin Constraint

Tags: pcb-design, altium, error

I have a pad in a IC left unconnected. I have set No ERC on that pin in the schematics to suppress of all violations.

[image]

But I still get "Un-connected Pin Constraint" error in PCB.

[image]

How can I suppress this error in PCB editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not come up with a good direct answer to the question, but here's something to consider regarding this rule.

I've personally never used this rule and from reading the [documentation](http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27164839&navigatingVersions=true) it appears that it is redundant anyway:

> [This rule] detects pins that have no net assigned and no connecting tracks.

Basically, this rule will only find pins which have **no net** assigned to them. NC pins are very common, so you should instead use the Un-Routed nets rule on the PCB level.

Unconnected pins should be checked on the schematic level (run ERC before pushing changes to the PCB) and you can use No ERC to mark the pins that are unconnected by design.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a lack of synchronization between the schematic and PCB. Try Project->Show differences, and make sure you've compiled everything with no errors before you do Design->Update PCB

Edit: As Armandas notes the ERC directives are not transferred, so one way would be to alter the design rules to not check for unconnected pins. You can do that either by changing the rules or by not checking during DRC (uncheck the box for Un-connected pin).

[image]

[image]

Comment: No ERC directives are not transferred to the PCB, so synchronization would not have an effect on the error.

Comment: @Armandas Hmm... looking at my setup here there is no rule under unconnected pin in Design Rules, which probably explains why I've never seen the error.